# Want to call an api, when user close tab or browser. Is there any function or library for react or any paid tool for that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call an api when user close window or tab. Is there any way ? This very important task for me. The way needs to work anyhow.

I tried old method like `unload` and `pagehide` also react library. I want this method working

Comment: It will *never* work 100%. If you absolutely *rely* on that for your app, you need to rethink it. Simplest example: the browser suddenly crashes, or you lose network connection.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I think there can be a way to do it .

Comment: @ShahzadSiddique There are multiple ways to achieve the requirement.

Comment: @deceze _"Simplest example: the browser suddenly crashes, or you lose network connection."_ We can use those events for our use case. The user uploads a `ReadableStream`; that streams will remain active until closed, cancelled or aborted by the user, or network error, which are observable in the server, then the server does stuff.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: I think [link](https://github.com/WICG/pending-beacon/blob/main/docs/fetch-later-api.md)`fetchLater()`  API Needs to work in this case, I need to check whether it works or not

Comment: A websocket connection with a regular heartbeat is your actual best bet. It’ll need to be timeout based, so you cannot detect a sudden crash immediately, but within a number of seconds.

Comment: I think It would be best with websocket connection

Comment: Use Websockets ! When a disconnection happens, you can easily get that event !

Comment: I did with websocket

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There is [`fetchLater()`](https://github.com/WICG/pending-beacon/blob/main/docs/fetch-later-api.md).

See [Intent to Prototype: fetchLater API](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/KXnqpUpVwPQ).

The [Chrome Platform Status](https://chromestatus.com/feature/4654499737632768) entry

> fetchLater() is a JavaScript API to request a deferred fetch. Once called, the request is queued by the browser, and will be invoked in one of the following scenarios:
>
> • The document is destroyed.
>
> • After a certain time.
>
> Motivation
>
> ...
>
> To simplify this issue and make beaconing more reliable, we propose adding a stateful JavaScript API where a page can register that it wants a beacon (or beacons) issued when it unloads or the page is hidden. Developers can populate beacon(s) with data as the user uses the page, and the browser ensures beacon(s) are reliably sent at some point in time. This frees developers from worrying about which part of the page lifecycle to send their beacon calls in.

Note, the requirement is also possible using a Web extension.

Comment: Note, this is also possible using other means with existing Web API's, such as a `ServiceWorker`. On the server side if/when the client posts a half-duplex stream to the server the server code can do stuff when the never-ending upload stream connection is closed, cancelled, or aborted by the client.

Comment: Thanks let try to implement better one